# What are the parameters that I need to consider when selecting an ESD diode?

Tags: voltage, resistors, diodes, power-electronics, esd

I'd like to know what the specifications are that I need to check in the datasheet of an ESD diode when selecting an ESD protection diode for high-speed interfaces such as Ethernet or USB.

I'd be very grateful if anyone can share their experience along with an example. I am looking for best practices.

Also, I am working on automotive and commercial products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By ESD diode, I take it you mean Transient Voltage Suppressor (TVS) diode...

In particular, the 'starting' characteristics for a TVS are:

- (1) Protection voltage threshold
- (2) Loading capacitance

(1) is derived from the requirements of the standard you are trying to meet. This is likely to be the (a) interface standard for Ethernet/USB but may be (b) a company standard or (c) a requirement you have established for yourself.

Usually (c) is derived from examples or good practice shown in an (a) or (b).

On (2), for a standardised interface, such as Ethernet or USB, it's taken from the requirements of that standard. For your own circuitry it's to be derived from the characteristics of that circuit.

Answer (score 1):

1. Decide **why** you are wanting to use ESD protection (assumed to be a TVS)
2. Figure out how much voltage your potential victims can survive
3. Decide which ESD spec you are working to (maybe EN 61000-4-2)
4. Choose a TVS diode that might "protect" without disrupting normal circuit operation
5. Research the equivalent circuit of the [ESD generator](https://www.youspice.com/simple-spice-esd-generator-circuit-based-on-iec61000-4-2-standard/2/) in the EN 61000-4-2 spec
6. Use a simulator and model the generator, cable and TVS together
7. Check what the peak voltage seen at the victim's port is
8. Iterate the design until you are happy that the circuit protects
9. Check that the peak power rating of the TVS is not exceeded
10. Choose a different TVS if necessary
11. Parallel-up TVS diodes if necessary
12. Perform real world testing
13. Go back and rethink if you have failures

- [Simple Spice ESD generator EN 6100-4-2](https://www.youspice.com/simple-spice-esd-generator-circuit-based-on-iec61000-4-2-standard/2/)

Comment: 4b) considering that the necessary interface bandwidth limits the maximum diode capacitance to x.x pF. 9b) considering that the diode may be exposed  not only to ESD strikes, but also also other transient shocks.

Comment: @tobalt yes 4b is important so I'll modify my (4) but, the question is about ESD so I'll not modify (9).

Answer (score 0):

If it can help, you have a quite exhaustive AN detailing surges and hazards (including ESD) but focused on automotive here:

[AN2689 : Protection of automotive electronics from electrical hazards,guidelines for design and component selection](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an2689-protection-of-automotive-electronics-from-electrical-hazards-guidelines-for-design-and-component-selection-stmicroelectronics.pdf)

Concerning the datarate, as explained by other members you have to pay attention to the parasitic line capacitance of the ESD protection diode.
Some vendors provide cut-off frequency fc of the ESD diode.
The rule of thumb is to have an ESD diode with fc > 0.35/tr, tr being the max rise time (10% to 90 %) of the communication protocol you are considering.